# Отсутствуют сертификаты SSL для моего приложения Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

У меня кастомный домен! Приложение Rails использует SSL. Как добавить SSL сертификаты в приложение?

Comment: На Heroku это платная услуга: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ssl

Comment: Это для старых версий! Сейчас вроде ACM  используется https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management. Но даже с тарифом Hobby у меня все равно нет сертификатов(

Comment: Необязательно для старых, это просто другая услуга, которая занимается сертификатами сама. Как бы там ни было, для приложения ничего не меняется, всё обеспечивает Heroku.

Comment: Установил  SSL Endpoint , установил тариф Hobby, но все равно при открытии страницы кастомного домена пишет : "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения"((

Comment: К сожалению, без пошагового описания того, что вы сделали, трудно что-либо посоветовать.

Comment: Через панель управления своим приложением я добавил следующие услуги: 1) SSL Endpoint, который стоит 20$; 2) Сделал апгрейд на тарфи Hobby; 3) Поставил галку автоматически получать сертификаты для кастомного домена; 4) Добавил DNS target кастомного домена в управление DNS зоны моего провайдера. После кастомный домен добавился и верефецировался в heroku. 5) Захожу на адрес кастомного домена мне пишет: "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения". Набираю команду heroku certs:info пишет : "myapp has no SSL certificates"(

Comment: Детали о вопросе полагается дописывать в вопрос.

Comment: Хм, а в руководстве по ACM же сказано, что с ним тоже можно использовать собственный сертификат. На этом фоне и правда непонятно, для чего SSL Endpoint.

Comment: Да самое главное и то и то не работает)) Я даже готов платить)))

Comment: В руководстве по ACM сказано, что включение не мгновенно происходит, и сказано, как проверять статус.

Comment: Написал в поддержку)! Буду ждать ответа... Потом отпишусь если что)

Comment: В поддержку обратился написав письмо на эл. почту(! Поддержка молчит(, билет не поймешь как сформировать(! На моем кастомном домене появился статус ОК. Переходя по адресу кастомного домена все равно пишет : " Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения"((

Comment: О, нашел как добавить билет в поддержку

Comment: В общем, проблема решена путем обращения с службу поддержки heroku. На мое получение сертификатов ssl было наложено ограничение по скорости. На текущий момент ограничение снято! D-side, спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решена путем обращения с службу поддержки heroku. На мое получение сертификатов ssl было наложено ограничение по скорости. На текущий момент ограничение снято! D-side, спасибо за помощь!)